How to display all posts of the custom type?
II've created a post type to add campaigns to my site. And I'm trying to get all the posts and display them on an archive.php page and also a single.php page to display the individual campaigns.
But when I display them on the site I get 404 errors: page not found.
I try to create two files to display alls campaigns:
This is my custom-post-type.php file
<?php
// Register a custom post type for campaigns
function fp_create_campaign_post_type() {
    register_post_type('campaign',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('Campagnes'),
                'singular_name' => __('Campagne'),
                'add_new' => __('Ajouter une campagne'),
                'add_new_item' => __('Ajouter une campagne'),
                'edit_item' => __('Modifier la campagne'),
                'new_item' => __('Nouvelle campagne'),
                'view_item' => __('Voir la campagne'),
                'search_items' => __('Rechercher parmi les campagnes'),
                'not_found' => __('Aucune campagne trouvée'),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __('Aucune campagne trouvée dans la corbeille')
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => "campaign",
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')
        )
    );
}
function custom_post_type_list_shortcode() {
    ob_start();

    $type = 'custom_post_type';
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => $type,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
    );
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($my_query->have_posts()) :
        echo '<ul>';
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
        endwhile;
        echo '</ul>';
    else :
        echo '<p>Aucune publication trouvée.</p>';
    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();

    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('custom_post_type_list', 'custom_post_type_list_shortcode');


add_action('init', 'fp_create_campaign_post_type');


This is my template-campaign.php file, it must display alls projects
<?php
/*
Template Name: Campagnes de financement participatif
*/

get_header();

//personnalisée pour afficher les articles de type "campaign"
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'campaign',
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // Afficher tous les articles
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) :
    while ($query->have_posts()) :
        $query->the_post();

        // Affichage du titre de l'article
        echo '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';

        // Affichage de la barre de progression
        echo fp_get_campaign_progress_bar(get_the_ID());

    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
else :
    echo 'Aucune campagne trouvée';

endif;

get_footer();
?>



How is your question JavaScript related? Why the JavaScript question tag? Also, I have the same question about your use of the CSS tag? If the tags are not relevant, you will want to remove them, since mistagging can result in frustration in users who follow those tags, come to the question and find no relevance. This may not be good for the health of your question on the site.

In your array "has_archive" argument is a boolean, so use 'has_archive' => true,… Maybe this will solve your issue.

I put "has_archive" in true : 'has_archive' => true, but it is the same problem

Check Permalink Settings:
Go to your WordPress admin dashboard.
Navigate to Settings > Permalinks.
Ensure that you've selected a permalink structure other than "Plain". Common choices include "Post name" or "Day and name".
Click "Save Changes" to update your permalink settings.
Create Template Files:
In your theme directory, create a new file named archive-campaign.php.
Add the following code to archive-campaign.php to display all campaigns:
<?php
get_header();
if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        // Display campaign content here
        the_title('<h2>', '</h2>');
        the_content();
    endwhile;
else :
    echo 'No Posts found.';
endif;

get_footer();
?>



Similarly, create a new file named **single-campaign.php** for displaying a single campaign. Customize it according to your needs.
Ensure that your template files are named correctly (**archive-campaign.php and single-campaign.php**) and are located in your theme directory.


I've added these files to the theme root (archive-campaign.php and single-campaign.php) and changed the permalink, but it's almost the same page not found problem when I try to display the site with this link: http://localhost/plugin-test/archive-campaign

Now it works correctly on the link http://localhost/plugin-test/campaign/ instead of http://localhost/plugin-test/archive-campaign/
But for single-campaign it's the same page not found issue using this link http://localhost/plugin-test/single-campaign/

'has_archive' => "campaign", should be 'has_archive' => 'true', and  'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'campagne' ) use for the slug  then you can use archive-campagne.php and  single-campagne.php now you can access the templates easily.
